# Swift, popup with tableview shows checkmark on positions where it was never clicked

Tags: swift, tableview

i try to show a popup where the user can multiple select rows to filter data. To do so i created this popupViewcontroller:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType == UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.checkmark{
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.none

        checkedCategories.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    }else{
        tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.checkmark
        checkedCategories.append(allcategories[indexPath.row])
    }
}
```

But the problem is if the user clicks on the first position, it shows also a checkmark at the last item. This error occurs only after scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This because cells are dequeued , so inside `cellForRowAt`

```
cell.accessoryType = checkedCategories.contains(indexPath.row) ? .checkmark : .none
```

Another note that may cause a crash to remove use

```
checkedCategories.removeAll(where:{ $0 == indexPath.row })
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a separate array to keep index paths. That's very bad practice.

Cells are reused. You have to make sure that every UI element is set to a defined state in `cellForRow`.

In your data model, preferable a struct or class add a property

```
var isSelected = false
```

In `cellForRow` set the checkmark according to the property

```
let item = datasource[indexPath.row]
cell.accessoryType = item.isSelected ? .checkmark : .none
```

In `didSelectRowAt` toggle `isSelected` and reload the row

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {   
     datasource[indexPath.row].isSelected.toggle()
     tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
}
```